# C++ Sockets recv() syscall returning -1

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I'm currently having a problem passing messages between a server and client.
As far as I know, I am properly following best practices for socket programming outlined by [Beej's Socket Programming Tutorial](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/).

When I run the two processes, the recv() syscall returns -1 (an error), rather than the number of bytes received. Also when trying to output the buf, there are a bunch of gobbledygook characters. Which makes sense, because of the error.

I'm wondering if someone could steer me in the right direction as to why I am having issues with recv()? The following are relevant code snippets.

Server:

```
struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
socklen_t addr_size;
int sockfd, newfd, byte_count, status;
char buf[512];
struct addrinfo hints,  *res;

//  first,  load  up  address  structs  with  getaddrinfo():
memset(&hints,  0,  sizeof  hints);
hints.ai_family  =  PF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype  =  SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

// get address info, print stuff if error
if((status = getaddrinfo("nunki.usc.edu",  "21957",  &hints,  &res)) !=0){
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo error: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
    exit(1);
}

//  make  a  socket:
if((sockfd  =  socket(res->ai_family,  res->ai_socktype,  res->ai_protocol)) == -1){
    cout << "socket fail" << endl;
}

// bind the socket to the port
bind(sockfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);

// required output
cout << "Phase1: Login server has TCP port number " << "21957 " 
     << "and IP address " << getIPfromHost("nunki.usc.edu") << endl;

// listen for incoming connections
listen(sockfd, 10);
cout << "after listen" << endl;

// halt until receipt 
addr_size = sizeof(their_addr);
newfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_size);
cout << "after accept" << endl;

// Now  that  we're  connected,  we  can  receive  some data
byte_count  =  recv(sockfd,  buf,  sizeof  buf,  0); 
printf("recv()'d  %d  bytes  of  data  in  buf\n",  byte_count);
printf("Msg is %s\n", buf);
```

Client:

```
struct addrinfo hints,  *res;
int  sockfd;

//  first,  load  up  address  structs  with  getaddrinfo():
memset(&hints,  0,  sizeof  hints);
hints.ai_family  =  AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype  =  SOCK_STREAM;
getaddrinfo("nunki.usc.edu",  "21957",  &hints,  &res);

//  make  a  socket:
if((sockfd  =  socket(res->ai_family,  res->ai_socktype,  res->ai_protocol)) == -1){
    cout << "socket fail" << endl;
}

// attempt connection to port
if(connect(sockfd,  res->ai_addr,  res->ai_addrlen) == -1){
    cout << "connect fail" << endl;
}

// send message to server
cout << "sockfd " << sockfd << endl;
int byte_count = send(sockfd, "Hello", 5, 0); 
cout << byte_count << endl;
```

The following is the output for Server:

```
Phase1: Login server has TCP port number 21957 and IP address 68.181.201.3
after listen
after accept
recv()'d  -1  bytes  of  data  in  buf
Msg is ÿhÿ?sÈ
Glæ
```

The following is the output for Client:

```
sockfd 4
5
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are calling `recv` on the wrong socket. You need to `recv` on `newfd`:

```
byte_count = recv(newfd, buf, sizeof buf, 0); /* newfd instead of sockfd. */
```

Now that that's out of the way,

> As far as I know, I am properly following best practices for socket
>   programming

I completely disagree.

- You are not checking return statuses for `listen`, `bind`, `getaddrinfo` etc
- There's not `strerror` or `perror` in your program

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm surprised at this oversight. Also, i'll be adding in the return statuses and error output. I was admittedly a bit lazy with that.

Answer (score 2):

You want to recv() using the socket returned from accept()

```
byte_count  =  recv(newfd,  buf,  sizeof  buf,  0);
```

Comment: Thank you! Fast responses tonight.. sheesh

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I shouldn't write this as an answer, but as a comment. Nevertheless, IMHO your use of `getaddrinfo()` seems wrong to me.

- On the client side, it is supposed to be called and then iterated through the results until a connection can be established.

  so

  ```
  struct addrinfo * r2
  sockfd = -1;
  for (r2=res; r2; r2=r2->ai_next) {
      //  make  a  socket:
      if((sockfd  =  socket(res->ai_family,  res->ai_socktype,  res->ai_protocol)) == -1){
          continue; // next result
      }

      // attempt connection to port
      if(connect(sockfd,  res->ai_addr,  res->ai_addrlen) == -1){
          close(sockfd);
          sockfd = -1;
          continue;
      }
  }
  if (sockfd == -1) {
      // do error handling
  }
  ```

  In this way, you can check all possible connections.
- On the server side, it is rather unusual to use `getaddrinfo()`. Normally, you would create an IPv6 socket and enable it to listen for IPv4 as well by using `setsockopt()` to unset the `IPV6_V6ONLY` flag. In this way, the socket listens to both IPv6 and IPv4. (Alas, not on WIndows XP AFAIK.)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with calling getaddrinfo server side, it's still a convenient API. `AI_PASSIVE` should've been set though.

Comment: Thanks! That was completely new to me, and so I [have a question about that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113805/usage-of-ai-passive)...

Answer (score 0):

The `sockfd` is just useed for listening the clients, `newfd` is used for data transmitting.