# Usage of getaddrinfo() with AI_PASSIVE

Tags: sockets, serversocket, getaddrinfo

The `getaddrinfo()` function not only allows for client programs to efficiently find the correct data for creating a socket to a given host, it also allows for servers to bind to the correct socket - in theory.

I just [learned about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111044/c-sockets-recv-syscall-returning-1/8111252#comment9950077_8111252) and started to play around with it via Python:

```
from socket import *
for i in getaddrinfo(None, 22, AF_UNSPEC, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP, AI_PASSIVE): i
```

yields

```
(2, 1, 6, '', ('0.0.0.0', 22))
(10, 1, 6, '', ('::', 22, 0, 0))
```

what makes me wonder about if there is something wrong.

What exactly am I supposed to do with these answers? Should I

- make a `listen()`ing socket of all of these answers, or should I
- just pick the first one which really works?

The example in the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo) suggests me to only take the first one and be happy with it if it is error-free, but then I only get a connection via IPv4 n my example.

But if I try all of them, I have to worry with 2 server sockets, which is unnecessary due to the fact that IPv6 server sockets also listen to IPv4 if certain conditions are met (OS, socket flags etc.).

Where am I thinking wrong?

---

EDIT: Obviously, I'm not thinking wrong, but my PC does the wrong thing. I use the default `/etc/gai.conf` shipped with OpenSUSE. It would be nice if anyone could point me towards the right direction.

EDIT 2: In the given case, `strace` gives the following calls made internally after reading `/etc/gai.conf` (now with port 54321, as I thought that using port 22 might have some bad influence, which was not the case):

```
socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(54321), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = 0
getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(38289), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::1", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, [28]) = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNSPEC, sa_data="\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"}, 16) = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(54321), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(60866), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::ffff:127.0.0.1", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, [28]) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
```

Obviously, the decision is intended to take place according to the results of the `getsockname()` calls...

BTW: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc/+bug/673708 and the other bug reports mentionned there confirm my observations. Several people there claim that the new behaviour is correct, so I'm obviously stuck to using `AF_INET6`... :-(

Comment: The easiest thing is just to pass INADDR_ANY as the IP address in your call to bind(), and then you'll have a socket that is listening on all interfaces and you don't have to worry about getaddrinfo() or multiple listening sockets.

Comment: But with `INADDR_ANY` I am limited to IPv4. I would like to cover IPv6 and IPv4.

Comment: That's incorrect.... for IPv6 there is the constant in6addr_any that works the same.  (Really both constants are just more readable names for zero; specifying a zero address to bind to gives you wildcarding behavior)  Example code here:  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzab6%2Frzab6xacceptboth.htm

Comment: I was sure I've read that it's specified that `AF_INET6` should be returned first, but now I can't find that. So I suppose I might've been mistaken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `getaddrinfo` is returning the wrong result for some reason. It's supposed to return the IPv6 socket first. The only thing I can think of is if your OS detects that your system has a low prio IPv6 (6to4 or Teredo) and avoids them, IMO wrongly so in that case. Edit: Just noticed my own computer does the same thing, I use 6to4.

However, you can either listen to both of them, or use `AF_INET6` instead of `AF_UNSPEC`. Then you can do setsockopt to disable `IPV6_V6ONLY`.

getaddrinfo does the reasonable thing here and returns all applicable results (though in the wrong order, as I mentioned). Both one and two listen sockets are valid approaches, depending on your application.

Comment: I have a tunneling endpoint in my LAN. My PC has a `192.168` IPv4 and a "regular" `2001:4dd0:` IPv6, so normally, IPv6 should get priority, as it does as a client. As a server, however, it uses indeed the wrong order, as shown. So I'll be going to use `AF_INET6` directly and omit the `getaddrinfo()` step. Or does anyone have an idea how I could correct this behaviour?

Comment: After having made quite a lot of research, it seems that the "wrong result order" is not unusual and that `AF_INET6` is the only way to go. Not very beautiful, but that's life... Anyway, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

JFTR: It seems now that the program given in the manpage is wrong.

There are two possible approaches for listening to both IP types:

1. Create only a IPv6 socket and switch off the v6 only flag:

   ```
   from socket import *
   s = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM)
   s.setsockopt(IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, 0)
   s.bind(...)
   ```

   resp.

   ```
   from socket import *
   ai = getaddrinfo(None, ..., AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0, AI_PASSIVE)[0]
   s = socket(ai[0], ai[1], ai[2])
   s.setsockopt(IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, 0)
   s.bind(ai[4])
   ```

   Pros:

   - simpler to handle

   Cons:

   - doesn't work under XP (AFAIK) - there are two different protocol stacks
2. work with two sockets and switch on the v6only flag:

   ```
   from socket import *
   aii = getaddrinfo(None, ..., AF_UNSPEC, SOCK_STREAM, 0, AI_PASSIVE)
   sl = []
   for ai in aii:
       s = socket(ai[0], ai[1], ai[2])
       if ai[0] == AF_INET6: s.setsockopt(IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, 1)
       s.bind(ai[4])
       sl.append(s)
   ```

   and handle all sockets in `sl` in accepting loop (use `select()` or nonblocking IO to do so)

   Pros:

   - uses a (nearly) protocol independent handling with `getaddrinfo()`
   - works under XP as well

   Cons:

   - complicated to handle